# select check box particular column should show and others should disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

- I am able to display the grid and right click menu on the grid
- when I right click a menu opens with checkbox in that.
- when I slect check box particular column should show and others should disappear.
- I targeted using data attribute but its not working.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code below
  http://jsfiddle.net/e2Lsjcx0/

```or-tag-here
 $("tr th[data-field='codeLong']").hide();



    if ($('input.checkbox_check').prop('checked')) {
      //blah blah
      alert("checked");

      $("tr th[data-field='codeLong']").show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding

```
$('.checkbox_check').on('click', function () {
      alert($(this).attr('checked'));
      $('th[data-field="codeLong"]').hide();
    });
```

Updated link

http://jsfiddle.net/e2Lsjcx0/13/

Comment: hey but entire column should disappear :(